# App is not getting launched in iOS device

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst

I have used IBM Mobilefirst Foundation 8.0 along with cordova to create a simple HelloWorld app. When I try launching the build through Xcode I am getting "Library not loaded" error(screenshot attached) in the console log.[reference image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bqxKI.png)

Answer (score 0):

How did you build the app?

Make sure you have done the following:

1. Created a Cordova app ([using the optional MFP template](https://mobilefirstplatform.ibmcloud.com/tutorials/en/foundation/8.0/application-development/sdk/cordova/#adding-the-sdk))
2. Added the iOS platform

   If you used the MFP template, this will ensure the MobileFirst SDK is installed once you have added the iOS platform.
3. Run `cordova prepare`
4. Run `cordova build`

   Open the your-project\platforms\ios*.xcodeproj file in Xcode
5. Run the project in Xcode

Comment: Yes, I did the same steps. But this issue is not happening consistently. Sometimes it comes up even if I follow the same steps.

Comment: This in all likelyhood related to Cordova, as MobileFirst is only a Cordova plug-in and the build process belongs to Cordova. Try updating to Cordova CLI 6.5.0 and cordova-ios@4.4.3 (remove and re-add the iOS platform). Also clear any Cordova caches (google update it).